# ggplot combine layer and keep legend group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a PCA plot with different legend title

data:

```
dataWithLang <- data.frame(
  PC1 = rnorm(100),
  PC2 = rnorm(100),
  PopLang = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  Label = sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

dataWithLocang <- data.frame(
  PC1 = rnorm(50),
  PC2 = rnorm(50),
  PopLoc = sample(c("X", "Y", "Z"), 50, replace = TRUE),
  Label = sample(1:3, 50, replace = TRUE)
)
```

create a plot

```
# plot a
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=dataWithLang, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = PopLang), alpha = 0.45)

p2 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=dataWithLocang, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = PopLoc))
```

output:
[image]

Now I want to combine the two layer

```
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=dataWithLang, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = PopLang), alpha = 0.45) + 
  geom_point(data=dataWithLocang, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = PopLoc))
p
```

[image]

You can note the legend group is also combine to one, but I want the legend group as first plot

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use the `ggnewscale` package which allows for multiple scales and legends for the same aesthetic:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

set.seed(123)

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=dataWithLang, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = PopLang), alpha = 0.45) + 
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(data=dataWithLocang, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = PopLoc))
```

[image]